# Detect line shapes' end points

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

I have some rather large diagrams in Excel sheets, showing input and destination like so:

[image: excel circuit diagram]

Here the input `i/p_1` is treated as `signal_1` to the left of the marker line (red line), and it goes to the destinations `1` and `2`. All the text is typed in cells, and the arrows drawn as shapes.

I have to create a **table of inputs, signal names and destinations** like so:

[image: circuit element table]

How would I achieve this?

I was thinking that finding out the starting and ending points to the arrows, and then looking at the cells in the row above it would give me a good starting point.
But I do not know how to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea to retrieve the requested cells. It should be a good starting point to achieve your goal.

```
Sub DisplayArrowCells()
    Dim x As Shape
    For Each x In Shapes
       If InStr(x.Name, "Elbow Connector") = 1 Then
             Debug.Print _ 
                 x.TopLeftCell.Address & "," & x.TopLeftCell.Value _
                 & " <---- " & _
                 x.BottomRightCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address & "," & x.BottomRightCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```